# how to copy data from a textbox in a for loop to another textbox within the for loop

Tags: javascript, textbox, copy

I have 2 text boxes in the following loop. and I would like to copy data from one textbox to the other. the following are part of my codes

javascript

```
function copy(val) {
 var a = document.getElementById("textA"+val).value
 document.getElementById("textB"+val).value=a
}
```

html

```
<% int count1 = -1;
   for(int i=0; i<2; i++) { %>

    <td><input type="text" id= "textA<%=i%>" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id= "textB<%=i%>" readonly/></td>

<% count1 = i;
}%>

<td><input type="button" value=" Copy " name="cb_copy" onClick="copy(<%=count1%>)"/>/td>
```

bt right now this only works for copying 1 value of the text box to the other. how do i copy all the textA values in this loop to its respective textB within this loop itself?

Thanks in advance for any possible help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the JS to:

```
function copy(val) {
   for(var i=0; i<val; i++) {
       var a = document.getElementById("textA"+i).value;

       document.getElementById("textB"+i).value = a;
   }
}
```

Comment: a for loop! thats how noob i am! :( lol! anyways this works great! only had to tweak to i<val+1 Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the indexes for *textA* start from 0 and are contiguous to the end, you can do something like:

```
var i = 0;
var source, target;

while (source = document.getElementById('textA' + i)) {

  if (target = document.getElementById('textB' + i)) {
    target.value = source.value;
  }
  i++;
}
```

This will test that the elements exist before trying to access them, which helps with not throwing errors, and doesn't require you to know how many pairs there are.